# Global function template overloading and const parameters

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

If I compile (gcc 4.6.0) and run this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> void F(/* const */ T& value) {
    std::cout << "T & " << value << std::endl;
}

template <typename T> void F(/* const */ T* value) {
    std::cout << "T * " << value << std::endl;
    F(*value);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    float f = 123.456;   
    float* pf = &f;

    F(pf);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
T * 0x7fff7b2652c4
T & 123.456
```

If I uncomment the const keywords I get the following output:

```
T & 0x7fff3162c68c
```

I can change `float* pf = &f;` to `const float* pf = &f;` to get the original output again, that's not the issue.

What I'd like to understand is why, when compiling with the const modifiers, overload resolution considers `const T& value` a better match than  `const T* value`for a non-const `float*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During overload resolution, overloads requiring no conversions beat overloads requiring some conversions, even if those conversions are trivial. Quoting the C++03 standard, [over.match.best] (§13.3.3/1):

> Define ICS*i*(`F`) as follows:
>
> - if `F` is a static member function, ICS*1*(`F`) is defined such that ICS*1*(`F`) is neither better nor worse than ICS*1*(`G`) for any function `G`, and, symmetrically, ICS*1*(`G`) is neither better nor worse than ICS*1*(`F`); otherwise,
> - let ICS*i*(`F`) denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts the *i*-th argument in the list to the type of the *i*-th parameter of viable function `F`. 13.3.3.1 defines the implicit conversion sequences and 13.3.3.2 defines what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than another.
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a *better* function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments *i*, ICS*i*(`F1`) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS*i*(`F2`), and then
>
> - for some argument *j*, ICS*j*(`F1`) is a better conversion sequence than ICS*j*(`F2`), or, if not that,
> - `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization, or, if not that,
> - `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.5.2, or, if not that,
> - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F1` to the destination type (i.e., the type of the entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F2` to the destination type.

When `const` is present, in order to call the overload taking a reference, no conversion is necessary -- `T` is deduced to be `float*` and the argument is `float* const&`. However, in order to call the overload taking a pointer, `float` would need to be converted to `float const` for said overload to be viable. Consequently, the overload taking a reference wins.

Note, of course, that if `pf` were changed to be a `float const*`, the behavior would go back to the way you expected because the overload taking a pointer would no longer require a conversion.